# How can I use Vue <Suspense> in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I have tried so many ways to use Suspense component in laravel blade template and since components are accessed using lowercase with hyphens, for example LoginComponent.vue can be accessed using `<login-component></login-component>`. I have tried `<Suspense></Suspense>` and `<suspense></suspense>` but I get an error saying custom component is not defined.

Is there a way I need to import it or do I have to register the component somewhere?

If you have any idea please drop it.. every contribution counts.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you have `Suspense` available in your VueJS 3.x version?

Comment: `<Suspense>` is a built in component - what version of vuejs are you using?

Comment: I'm using vue 2.6.12 in laravel

Comment: Please how do I know if suspense is available?

Comment: FYI: 3.x is not a version of vuejs, usually the version is something like 3.0.1 - though, looking at the history of vue3, seems `suspense` has been there since 3.0.0

Comment: oh, you've edited the comment .. why did you tag the question `vuejs3` when you are using vuejs 2? Suspense is available in vuejs3, but not in vuejs2 - there's your issue